# APIDocJS - Generating Navigation Links Using Method Type and @apiName Instead of Description

Tags: api-doc

When I generate my API documentation, the links to each individual API on the left hand side of the index page are currently being generated from the description of the API.

```
@api {post} /my/endpoint **this is the current link name**
```

I would like the link name to be a combination of the method type (in the above example **post**) and the *@apiName*. For this block comment:

```
@api {post} /my/endpoint description of API
@apiName Create Cake
```

I would like the link text for this API to be *POST - Create Cake*

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own templates, by copying the template/ folder; see http://apidocjs.com/#template

For what you want to achieve, in index.html, in the first block, add

```
<span class="method">{{ type }}</span>
```

and add a rule in style.css :

```
.method { text-transform: uppercase }
```

You also can change the call to {{ title }} to a call to {{ name }} (It seems to be the case in the template today)